# Start Google search query from activity - Android

Tags: android, search

I was wondering if there is an easier way (or any way) to start a Browser with a Google search query. For example user can select a certain word or phrase and click a button and the activity will start the browser with the Google search query.

Thank you.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You can do this quite easily with a few lines of code (assuming you want to search Google for 'fish'):

```
String escapedQuery = URLEncoder.encode(query, "UTF-8");
Uri uri = Uri.parse("http://www.google.com/#q=" + escapedQuery);
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
startActivity(intent);
```

Otherwise, if you would rather start up your own Activity to handle the browsing, you should be able to do so with a WebView: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html

I think the better answer here is @zen_of_kermit's.  It would be nice though, if Android allowed a user to provide the Search engine has an extra though for the `ACTION_WEB_SEARCH`, rather than just using Google.

Comment: Thank you Nicholas. That is easy.

Comment: What activity would start to launch Google Search (the app, not browser)?

Comment: It's better the answer given by @zen_of_kermit , because the intent written by him it's focused on Google Searches, but using the right Intent Type.

Comment: @CarlosAlbertoMartínezGadea I am not sure that a correct answer warrants a downvote.  Typically, I would apply those to incorrect answers.  Usually, I would either not vote, or upvote a correct answer...

Comment: I guess you are right, I didn't think about it on that way. I'll remove my downvote as soon as I can, cause the system blocked it temporarily.

Comment: @CarlosAlbertoMartínezGadea To be honest, I am not all that concerned about a downvote, I just thought I might point out the spirit of this site is to provide options for developers stuck on something, and to make those options visible.

Comment: I think that this is exactly what I was trying to show, when I voted the @zen_of_kermit answer. But I thought your option wasn't completely right, even if it could be effective. I don't know if you understand what I mean.

Comment: @nicholas.hauschild  how can i show search results of google query inside our activity

Comment: @nicholas.hauschild: any way to parse the results and save it in the database for future use?

Answer (score 69):

The Intent class defines an action specifically for web searches:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_WEB_SEARCH

Here's an example of how to use it:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_WEB_SEARCH);
intent.putExtra(SearchManager.QUERY, query); // query contains search string
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: No activity found to handle intent!

Comment: put it in `try { ... } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) { }` mb some users phones really don't have a web-browser... xD

Answer (score 7):

the `#` gave me trouble:

```
Uri uri = Uri.parse("https://www.google.com/search?q="+query);
Intent gSearchIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
activity.startActivity(gSearchIntent);
```

Answer (score 5):

I recently tried this. This appears to work fine. If any modifications to be done let me know as I am new to android development.

```
mEdit   = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText);
```

in your click view,

```
String q = mEdit.getText().toString();
                        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_WEB_SEARCH );
                        intent.putExtra(SearchManager.QUERY, q);
                        startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
                String Search= null;
                try {
                    Search= URLEncoder.encode(s, "UTF-8");
                } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                Uri uri = Uri.parse("http://www.google.com/#q=" + Search);
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
```

Comment: This variant was working, but Google change it and not it is not working.
Currently working variant is:
https://www.google.com/search?q=