# Start intent to open google link just like the I am feeling lucky button

Tags: android, android-intent

I have a button in my activity and I want when pressed to fire an intent that will start some page just like a "I'am feeling lucky" on google

meaning something like this

```
public void startIntent(String textToSearch){
//fire an intent that will open the page just like when I open
//google.com and enter the textToSearch text and press I am feeling lucky
}
```

How can I do this ?

Comment: something like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4800575/start-google-search-query-from-activity-android. e.g. pass some vars to the url you are opening

Answer (score 1):

This is what I needed

```
public void startIntent(String textToSearch){
Uri uri = Uri.parse("http://www.google.com/#q="+textToSearch);
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
startActivity(intent);
}
```