# How to send Intent to pass something to Google search

Tags: android, android-intent

I am making an android app and in that Can I send Intent to pass something to Google search and can display the search page result ?

I hope I am clearly specifying my question.

So, Please help me in this.

Thank you all in advance.

Comment: i guess you are looking for this :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4800575/start-google-search-query-from-activity-android

Comment: @Nibha Jain oh yeah..looking for the same..thanks

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are accepting the value from user in edit text.

```
String url = "http://www.google.com/#q=";
String query = edittext.getText().toString().trim();
String final_url = url + query;
```

Now on search button click, do the following

```
Uri uri = Uri.parse(final_url);
startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri));
```

This will launch your web browser and show you the google search result.