# Uri.Parse deprecated

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.android, uri

I have a barcode scanner app. I am trying to scan barcode and search at google. But when I try to search as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4800575/start-google-search-query-from-activity-android), It says `Uri.Parse()` *deprecated*. I couldn't find anything useful and `Uri` documentation does not say anything about it.

**Uri Documentation**

> https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/Uri.html

Is there any other option or replacement it?

Comment: Why i got downvote here? I am confused.

Comment: my android studio does not say that (as you noticed the docs also dont say a word on it), so you can forget it (and blame Visual Studio)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You are referencing the `Uri` from `System` in which `Parse` is `Obsolete`:

```
[ObsoleteAttribute("The method has been deprecated. It is not used by the system.
protected virtual void Parse()
```

The SO question you are referencing is using **`Uri`** from the **`Android.Net`** namespace:

```
Android.Net.Uri uri = Android.Net.Uri.Parse("http://www.google.com/#q=fish");
var intent = new Intent(Intent.ActionView, uri);
StartActivity(intent);
```